# Deploying Jersey resources into a Servlet 3.0 API aware container fails miserably

Tags: java, jetty, jersey, jax-rs, servlet-3.0

<sub>(I've accidentally deleted the gist that I'm referring to in this question; sorry for the inconvenience.)</sub>

## The Question

I'm trying to use the [Servlet 3.0 API](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-mrel-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-mrel-spec.pdf) to deploy Jersey root resources (those annotated with the [`@Path`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation) following the [Jersey's user guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e196).

I've created a [gist at GitHub](https://gist.github.com/1283640) containing two classes: [`Foo.java`](https://raw.github.com/gist/1283640/9b4b0a0ee210cd07efbcb00477ac9afea1b5a39c/Foo.java) which is a subclass of [`Application`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) that exposes [`Bar.java`](https://raw.github.com/gist/1283640/925475f1c6e244fca3dae8ff129d96e689b33e38/Bar.java) (the resource class) through its [`getClasses()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getClasses%28%29) method. (There is a [`pom.xml`](https://raw.github.com/gist/1283640/2270842f0ff53da1c9689ab7eddeece5c97ccc33/pom.xml) too, so anyone can try this out for herself/himself easily.)

However, when I try to deploy the packaged war to a Jetty 8.0.x instance I get the [output available here at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=UwmsbMkA).

`Foo.java` gets called, its `getClasses()` method gets called too while `Bar.java` is never invoked.

I can reach Jetty's welcome page at `http://localhost:8080/`, however I neither can reach `http://localhost:8080/foo` or `http://localhost:8080/foo/bar`. The latter two results in the following error:

> **Not Found ERROR**
>
> custom 404 page

**What could be the problem? Am I doing something wrong here?**

## The Answer

Given the WAR I've used (`test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`) my application path became `http://localhost:8080/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/foo/bar` instead of `http://localhost:8080/foo/bar`. See what I did there? Good. Engrave this in your mind people or lose 3-to-5 precious hours of your life!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I've solved the problem.

My application's path isn't at `http://localhost:8080/foo/bar` but at `http://localhost:8080/<the name of my war file>foo/bar`. So given the `pom.xml` I've posted it becomes `http://localhost:8080/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/foo/bar`.

I hate WAR files.

Answer (score 0):

You've got one call with **@Path**, while the other have **@ApplicationPath** with NO @Path on the method.

As you can [here](http://netbeans.dzone.com/articles/how-to-combine-rest-and-ejb-31),

> JAX-RS API (from version 1.1.4) introduced  a specific annotation ( @javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath ), that provides an alternative to web.xml configuration:

But you'll need at least a @Path on the called method. However, the simplest thing is probably to start with a classic old web.xml, then using @Path on Resources. You'll get plenty of exemples in the web, while @ApplicationPath is not common.

Comment: `You've got one call with @Path, while the other have @ApplicationPath with NO @Path on the method.` Which is *the* method that should have an extra `@Path` annotation? Do you say that `Bar#bar()` should have a `@Path` annotation? I think you are wrong then. `@Path("bar")` on top of `Bar.java` and `@GET` on its `bar()` method indicates that `bar()` will (or should) be called on a `GET` request to `http://localhost:8080/foo/bar`. Other than this: `@ApplicationPath` is there to redeem the usage of a `web.xml` which it does perfectly. The `log` says that the path `.../foo/*` gets registered.

Comment: I think you should have @Path on the Foo.getClass, because the servlet only know to find the Resource path, but not the proper method. I may be wrong, I've nerver user ApplicationPath, because it's quite recent.

Comment: `Foo.java` is not a JAX-RS resource, but an `Application`. Annotating it with `@ApplicationPath("foo")` essentially means, that you create a servlet for Jersey with `<url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>`. This works without a hitch. However I've tried annotating `Foo.java` with `@Path("foo")`, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: OK, I got the Application stuff :) It looks like GET http://localhost:8080/foo/bar should do the job as long as the server is able to fetch the Application class at startup. 
Do you have the lovely CLASSESCLASSESCLASSESCLASSESCLASSESCLASSESCLASSESCLASSES! displayed somewhere ? Wich server are you using ?

Comment: Please refer to the question... Anyway, the log I linked contains the *lovely* lines you mention, also I've mentioned that I'm using Jetty.

Comment: According to Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_(Web_server)#History), only Jetty 8 is fully Servlet 3.0 compliant and probably not the default download. I think that @ApplicationPath will require all the Servlet 3.0 implementation so you should consider  using Glassfish 3.1+ or use a web.xml

Comment: Please refer to my answer and get a laugh or two! :)

Answer (score 0):

While this wasn't your problem, if you're trying to deploy in Jetty 8 in Cargo, you would likely have hit this bug: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/CARGO-1133